# A Question Regarding Limitations

Tags: calculus, limits, poisson-distribution

How many ways can we calculate these limitations about factorial?
$$1+a+\frac{a^2}{2!}+\frac{a^3}{3!}+...+\frac{a^n}{n!}\\
\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}-+...+\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$$
I met this kind of limitations when I dealt with Poisson random variables and don't know how to solve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first converges to $e^a$ (it is the exponential series) and the latter is
the special case where $a=-1$, so converges to $e^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you. It's something related to Maclaurin series, right?

Comment: @HanWang Yes...